Expected server HTML to contain a matching <span> in <div>
<div className="menu-link junomenu">
    <span className="menu-icon junoicon">
        <i className="ki-outline ki-category fs-3"></i>
    </span>
    <span className="menu-title">Dashboards</span>
    <span className="menu-arrow d-lg-none"></span>
</div>

this code have problem: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .
i tried to fix it but i can't fix it, i don't know it have what problem.
i see this code is very Normal and don't have issue...
I want to everyone can help me fix this code...
